# Spring Integration how to return back payload together with exception with advice?

Tags: spring-integration

We are using Spring Integration Split and Aggregate to parallel flow of sub messages for large request.

For error flow, would like the flow to handle the exception when all of the sub messages all processed, so that we could handle the exception at aggregate stage.

In order to archived above, we are consider to use advice with example:

```
    @Bean
    ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice example() {
        final var advice = new ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice();
        advice.setTrapException(true);
        advice.setOnFailureExpressionString("payload + ' exception:' + #exception");
        advice.setReturnFailureExpressionResult(true);
        return advice;
    }
```

Above example will return ErrorMessage as String together with payload and exception.

But what we require is that the payload, and exception as separated object, so that it can be handled in the error channel, we can then extract info from exception details and also using payload for other logic.

When google found payload can be return back as following, but then exception is not been captured.

```
advice.setOnFailureExpression(
                new FunctionExpression<Message<?>>(s ->
                        MessageBuilder
                                .withPayload(s.getPayload())
                                .copyHeaders(s.getHeaders()).build())
        );
```

Will Spring Integration give some example of how to archive above? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `FunctionExpression` is based on a plain `Function`, so it can have only one input argument. Therefore it is expected that you don't have an access to an exception as it would be possible with standard SpEL expression.

You can achieve something similar to that function logic via SpEL expression. However I'd suggest to go some Spring hooks from the SpEL, in particular the call of some bean.

So, to make it working something like this could be possible:

```
advice.setOnFailureExpressionString("@myFailureHandler.handleError(#root, #exception)");
```

Then you need to have a bean with that `myFailureHandler` name and have there an implemetation possible like this:

```
public Message<?> handleError(Message<?> failedMessage, Exception exception) {
    return MessageBuilder.fromMessage(failedMessage)
                  .copyHeaders("error", exception)
                  .build()
}
```

Or you can wrap that exception into a `MessageHandlingException` and place it into a payload for further error handling. However in this case I'm not sure how your aggregator will react for an exception payload.